# Django adding new models, Exception Type: OperationalError Exception Value: no such table:

Tags: python, django

I am trying to learn how to use Django and I made a new model, and when syncing the db and making migrations i am keep getting this error. How can I fix this or what am I doing wrong?

*I have tried running python manage.py makemigrations, manage.py migration, manage.py makemigrations --syncdb nothing seems to work.*

```
   Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8080/admin/terra/terraformrepolist/

Django Version: 3.0.3
Python Version: 3.7.3
Installed Applications:
['terra.apps.TerraConfig',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\WonderUS\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\WonderUS\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 396, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

The above exception (no such table: terra_terraformrepolist) was the direct cause of the following exception:
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\WonderUS\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\WonderUS\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\WonderUS\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\WonderUS\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 607, in wrapper
    return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\WonderUS\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\WonderUS\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\WonderUS\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 231, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\WonderUS\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\WonderUS\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\WonderUS\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1678, in changelist_view
    cl = self.get_changelist_instance(request)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\WonderUS\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 741, in get_changelist_instance
    sortable_by,
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\WonderUS\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\views\main.py", line 98, in __init__
    self.get_results(request)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\WonderUS\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\views\main.py", line 226, in get_results
    result_count = paginator.count
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\WonderUS\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\WonderUS\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\paginator.py", line 91, in count
    return c()
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\WonderUS\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 397, in count
    return self.query.get_count(using=self.db)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\WonderUS\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 517, in get_count
    number = obj.get_aggregation(using, ['__count'])['__count']
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\WonderUS\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 502, in get_aggregation
    result = compiler.execute_sql(SINGLE)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\WonderUS\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1144, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\WonderUS\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\WonderUS\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\WonderUS\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\WonderUS\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\WonderUS\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\WonderUS\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\WonderUS\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 396, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

Exception Type: OperationalError at /admin/terra/terraformrepolist/
Exception Value: no such table: terra_terraformrepolist
```

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/migrations/#the-commands

Comment: `./manage.py migrate`

Comment: Thank you seemed to fix my issue, thanks both of you!